# program using string function

Tags: c++, string, function, if-statement

i have a program of string, the program running, but the output is not right, i mean no identity of the condition, help me please..
so if any one can running the program please put it here

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double hour;
    char s1 [20]={'e','n','t','e','r',' ','a','n',' ','h','o','u','r'};
    char s2 [15]={'g','o','o','d',' ','m','o','r','n','i','n','g'};
    char s3 [15]={'g','o','o','d',' ','a','f','t','e','r',' ','n','o','o','n'};
    char s4 [15]={'g','o','o','d',' ','e','v','e','n','i','n','g'};
    char s5 [20];
    char s6 [15];
    strcpy (s5,s1);
    cout<<s5;
    cin>>hour;
    if(hour >= 6 && hour >=11.40)
    strcpy (s6,s4);
    cout<<s6;
    if (hour >= 11.41 && hour <= 12.59)
    if(hour >=1 && hour <=4.30)
    strcpy (s5,s3);
    cout<<s5;
    if(hour >= 4,31 && hour <= 5.59)
    strcpy (s5, s4);
    cout<<s5;

    strlen (s6);
    cout<<"every characters in the string is"<<s6;


    getch ();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please improve your english, it's a bit tough to understand what you need help with.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is incomprehensible and shows no research effort.

Comment: `hour >= 4,31` looks wrong .. it *won't* behave as expected. Also, use `if(..) { .. }` (note the braces) to have multiple statements in the `if`.

Comment: You have the wrong header. You need `string.h`. On the other hand, you have the right header, but you should be using `std::string` instead of C.

Comment: @user2864740 if am put brace the program running, but come out.

Answer (score 2):

Your strings aren't all terminated, so `strlen`, `<<`, and anything else expecting terminated strings will fall off the end of the array giving undefined behaviour.

Since this is C++, you want to use `std::string` for your strings:

```
std::string s1 = "enter an hour";
```

If you really want to mess around with C-style strings for some reason, then initialise them from a terminated string literal (or a character array, if you really, really hate readable code), letting the compiler deduce the correct length:

```
char s1[] = "enter an hour";
// or
char s1[] = {'e','n','t','e','r',' ','a','n',' ','h','o','u','r','\0'};
```

You also have a typo here:

```
hour >= 4,31  // should be 4.31
```

and here:

```
hour >=11.40 // should be <=
```

and you should try to indent the code to reflect its logical layout - it's very difficult to see whether or not the nested `if` blocks make any kind of sense.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to include `#include <cstring>` or `#include <string.h>`, or it shouldn't be to compile

Answer (score 0):

I think in first if statement you mean if(hour >= 6 && hour <=11.40)
Also strlen returns the string length, you need a variable to receive that return value.
And I don't understand why on earth are you using character array in C++

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to complicate things and enter the string character by character.
If you set them one by one you have to include the null termination. Otherwise strcpy could not know where to stop when copying.

Another think in you if condition you have to use a point `4.31` not with a camma `4,31`.

Just enter the phrase directly

```
char s1 [20]="enter an hour";
```

For the if statments use them this way:

```
if (hour > 6 && hour <= 11.41){
   strcpy(s6, s2);
   cout << s6;
}
else if (hour > 11.41 && hour <= 14){
//...
}
//... etc
```